# Number of Solutions of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{c}= \sum_{j=1}^{n} y_j^{c} $

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

**Problem:**

Given the power diophantine equation
 $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{c}= \sum_{j=1}^{n} y_j^{c} \tag{1}$$

where $(1)$ follows three conditions:

1. Variable $x_i \neq y_j$ for any indexes $i, j\leq n$.
2. Variable $x_i \neq x_k$ for any indexes $i, k\leq n$.
3. Constant exponent $c\geq 2$.

> Then, are there infinite solutions of $(1)$ for a fixed $c$ and a variable $n$ ?
>
> **Query**: Is there anything related to the above problem in the existing literature?

Please inform me if it exists in any literature, book, note or web page.

Comment: Hard question take a look at "Arithmetics" from Hindry

Comment: @Maman ,  r u referring to Waring's problem ?

Comment: This teacher is a lover of diophantine equations and solutions of polynomial equations. Find his book it could be very interesting ! I give you the complete reference : http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781447121305

Comment: This is called ***equal sums of like powers***. In particular, your post is the _balanced_ case where each side has the same number of terms. A google search should give many hits.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lander,_Parkin,_and_Selfridge_conjecture

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet–Tarry–Escott_problem